# How to send form with file without reload page?

Tags: ajax, spring

I trying to send form without reload page in the ajax, but I see, link on the file does not exist...

I have the next form:

```
<form id="settings" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    <input type="file" id="logo" style="display:none;" name="logo" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif">
    <button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
</form>
```

Ajax script:

```
$('#settings').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).serialize();
    alert(form); // file is not attached...
    $.ajax({
        url         : '/settings',
        type        : 'POST',
        crossDomain : false,
        data        : form,
        contentType : 'multipart/form-data',
        dataType    : 'json',
        progressData: false,
        cache       : false,
        success     : function(r){
            alert (111);
        }
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log('Error occured!');
    });
});
```

On the server side, I get the error:

> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

I tried not serialize form, and wrote instead `data : form` -> `data : new FormData(this)` This option causes an error "Illegal invocation". How to send form with file without reload page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a form with a file using AJAX without page reload, you need to use `FormData` to handle the file upload properly.

```html
<form id="settings" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Other form fields -->
    <input type="file" id="logo" name="logo" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif">
    <button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#settings').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        
        $.ajax({
            url: '/settings',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                alert('Form submitted successfully!');
                // Handle the response from the server
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('Error occurred!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```